# CSS fixed position div content cuts off in mobile landscape mode and will not scroll

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a position:fixed and a bunch of list items in it. When viewed on mobile devices in landscape mode the menu cuts off the list items and does not allow scrolling. Loading up this jsfiddle and changing the height of your browser to something around the 600px mark will illustrate the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/w55h3/1/

Notice the styling on #main-menu:

```
#main-menu {
...
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: In this kind of structure always give problem in mobile devices and also fixed position is not working in mobile devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the same in the below [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w55h3/2/). You can have a look

Changes:

```
.navbar{height:0; min-height:0;}
#main-menu {
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Thats almost there. It allows scrolling in the nav area separately from the scrolling in the content area. Is it possible to make the left and right columns scroll as one?

Comment: Change the postion from fixed to absolute in #main-menu - @novon

Comment: I just tried the fixed to absolute. IF the content area is larger in height than #main-menu the drop shadow stops at the same point as #main-menu (in other words doesn't reach the bottom of the page).

Comment: add a height: 564px; and border-radius:5px in #main-menu - @novon

Comment: Very nice this worked. I actually ended up applying the height to #main-menu .wrapper{} and moved the drop shadow from #main-menu to #main-menu .wrapper{} also. For some reason #main-menu was being restricted in height while its wrapper was not. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #main-menu {
        left: 0px;
    }
}
```

You have `left: -200px` which you override for the other screen sizes but not the smallest.

Comment: I did that to auto hide the menu when the site is viewed on a mobile device. This is an issue once the menu is actually opened (in portrait mode) or when the screen is in landscape mode (where the menu is automatically shown with the left:0px).

Comment: O, I see. Have you tried using `position: absolute` instead of `position: fixed`?

Answer (score 0):

That's the point about `position: fixed;`. The content stays at a fixed position, no matter what.

You can try a media query with a `max-height` for example

```
@media (max-height: 600px) {
    #main-menu {
        position: absolute;
        overflow: visible;
    }
}
```

This allows the main menu to scroll with the content container, when the height drops below a given threshold.

To see the shadow, you can add an appropriate height

```
height: 565px;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fKFWv/)

Comment: The drop shadow now only runs along the height of the height of #main-menu. Possible to make it run along the entire height of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with such code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1099px) and (max-height: 700px) {
#header .menu-topcategorymenu-container {
overflow-y: scroll;
   max-height:300px;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* works without it too */
}
```

}

1099px - mobile menu disappears at 1100, 700px - height of my screen occupied by mobile menu drop-down, 300px height of my screen for menu on iphone4